# how to add switches in list view and how to get on and off status on new activity

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to switch off all users in the next activity but I am not able to do it. I have switches for each items in the `listview` but I can't store or get status of each item.

I want to add switches to all items and I want to save all the status of the switches. I want to access all items with switches off in the new activity.

This is adminhome.java file which shows all listview item on this activity page:

```
package com.example.nilesh.loginpa;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Adminhome extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseAuth firebaseauth;
    DatabaseReference mref;
    Button btn;

    //private String uname;

    //private ArrayList<String> ulist = new ArrayList<>();

    List<UserProfile> userlist;
    ListView allusers;
    Switch switch1;

    //private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_adminhome);

        //firebaseauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsub);
        allusers = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvusers);
        userlist = new ArrayList<>();
        //arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ulist);
        //allusers.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                userlist.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot userprofileSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    UserProfile userProfile = userprofileSnapshot.getValue(UserProfile.class);
                    userlist.add(userProfile);
                }

                Userslist adapter = new Userslist(Adminhome.this,userlist);
                allusers.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is UserList.java file is used for save the items in the list view:

```
package com.example.nilesh.loginpa;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class Userslist extends ArrayAdapter <UserProfile> {
    private Activity context;
    private List<UserProfile> userlist;

    public Userslist(Activity context,List<UserProfile> userlist){
        super(context,R.layout.list_layout,userlist);
        this.context =context;
        this.userlist = userlist;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null, true);

        TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        TextView textViewemail = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewemail);
        Switch switch1 = (Switch) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.switch1);

        UserProfile userProfile = userlist.get(position);

        textViewName.setText(userProfile.getName());
        textViewemail.setText(userProfile.getEmail());

        return listViewItem;
    }


}
```

This is UserProfile.java code is used for access all the users detail from firebase:

```
package com.example.nilesh.loginpa;

public class UserProfile {
    public String name;
    public String email;
    public String age;
    public UserProfile(){
    }

    public UserProfile(String name, String email, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override

    public String toString(){
        return this.name + ":" + this.age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please se this examle. You need to have XML layout with the desired look of the list item (in this example, the list item consists of a textview and a togglebutton):

```
private class ShopItemListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private List<ShopItem> shopItems;

        private ShopItemListAdapter(List<ShopItem> shopItems) {
            this.shopItems = shopItems;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return shopItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return shopItems.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return shopItems.get(position).getId();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ShopItem shopItem = shopItems.get(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.shopitem, null);
                TextView textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.shopItemText);
                ToggleButton toggleButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.shopItemBought);

                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(toggleButton, textView);

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            // click listener must be set always no matter of convertView is or is not null
            // otherwise recycle view behaves strangely to checked states of toggle buttons
            viewHolder.shopItemBought.setOnClickListener(new ToggleBoughtListener(shopItem));
            viewHolder.shopItemBought.setChecked(shopItem.isBought());
            viewHolder.shopItemName.setText(shopItem.getName());
            return convertView;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            ToggleButton shopItemBought;
            TextView shopItemName;

            ViewHolder(ToggleButton shopItemBought, TextView shopItemName) {
                this.shopItemBought = shopItemBought;
                this.shopItemName = shopItemName;
            }
        }
        private class ToggleBoughtListener implements View.OnClickListener {

            final ShopItem shopItem;

            private ToggleBoughtListener(ShopItem shopItem) {
                this.shopItem = shopItem;
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                shopItem.setBought(!shopItem.isBought());
                repository.update(shopItem);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i am not able understand this code can u help me please i am new to android

Comment: You have ListView item. This ListView needs adapter which is BaseAdapter. This adapter connects ListView with your data. Method getView returns list item view for each item. ViewHolder pattern helps you to tweak performance because of recycling of items.

Comment: ok thank you and can u tell me how do i get items in new activity whose switch is off